# Cannot save data from Ant Design <Input.Group>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, antd

I tried making two input fields one for dimensions and one for weight, and both had seperate select drop down to allow the user to select a unit. [I saw on Ant design docs that they had something similar](https://4x.ant.design/components/input/#:%7E:text=%3CInput%20defaultValue%3D%2226888888%22), so I tried using that.

This is how I wanted it to be like:
[image]

Now i have filled my form with many other fields and they work just fine, on clicking the save button, I am not getting any data entered in the fields for dimensions or weight, nor their units. I have a standard save function which is called on 'onFinish' event:

```
const handleSubmit = (data) => {
  console.log('data', data);
  submit(data);
};
```

This is my code to generate the fields.

```
<Form onFinish={handleSubmit} >
<Row style={{ justifyContent: 'left' }}>
  {<Col span={8}>
    <div className="p-2 lbh-input">
      <Form.Item
        name="dimensions"
        key="dimensions"
        label="Dimensions &nbsp;&nbsp; (l x b x h)">
        <Input.Group>
          <Input
            key='length'
            name='length'
            style={{ width: '15%' }}
            type="number"
          />
          <Input
            key='breadth'
            name='breadth'
            style={{ width: '24%' }}
            addonBefore="x"
            type="number"
          />
          <Input
            key='height'
            name='height'
            style={{ width: '25%' }}
            addonBefore="x"
            type="number"
          />
          <Select name='dimension_unit' key='dimension_unit' defaultValue="cm">
            <Option value="mm">mm</Option>
            <Option value="cm">cm</Option>
            <Option value="inch">inch</Option>
            <Option value="feet">feet</Option>
            <Option value="m">m</Option>
          </Select>
        </Input.Group>
      </Form.Item>
    </div>
  </Col>
  }
  {
    <div className="p-2">
      <Form.Item
        key="weight"
        name="weight"
        label="Weight">
        <Input.Group>
          <Input
            style={{ width: '50%' }}
            type="number"
            key="weight"
            name="weight"
            label="Weight"
            className='noborderradius'
          />
          <Select defaultValue="kg" name="weight_unit" key="weight_unit">
            <Option value="kg">kg</Option>
            <Option value="tonne">tonne</Option>
            <Option value="g">g</Option>
          </Select>
        </Input.Group>
      </Form.Item>
    </div>}
</Row>
<button>SUBMIT</button>
</Form>
```

As you can see, i have tried using everythihg I can like label,name,key but no matter what happens, I get no data being sent no matter what I type in these two fields. What am i missing? Am i doing something wrong with `<Form.item>` ?
My ant design version is

```
"antd": "^4.3.4",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Input.Group` is just for layout purposes, it does not group all your inputs into a single `Form.Item`. You still need to wrap all your inputs with `Form.Item` and attach the names there. Use the `noStyle` property to not override the `Input.Group` styling.

Also, `defaultValue` will give you this warning:

> Warning: [antd: Form.Item] `defaultValue` will not work on controlled Field. You should use `initialValues` of Form instead.

So you can just do as it says, I've removed the styling for brevity

```
    <Form
      onFinish={handleSubmit}
      initialValues={{ dimension_unit: 'cm', weight_unit: 'kg' }}
    >
      <Form.Item label="Dimensions &nbsp;&nbsp; (l x b x h)">
        <Input.Group>
          <Form.Item name="length" noStyle>
            <Input type="number" />
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item name="breadth" noStyle>
            <Input type="number" addonBefore="x" />
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item name="height" noStyle>
            <Input type="number" addonBefore="x" />
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item name="dimension_unit" noStyle>
            <Select>
              <Option value="mm">mm</Option>
              <Option value="cm">cm</Option>
              <Option value="inch">inch</Option>
              <Option value="feet">feet</Option>
              <Option value="m">m</Option>
            </Select>
          </Form.Item>
        </Input.Group>
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item label="Weight">
        <Input.Group>
          <Form.Item name="weight" noStyle>
            <Input type="number" />
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item name="weight_unit" noStyle>
            <Select>
              <Option value="kg">kg</Option>
              <Option value="tonne">tonne</Option>
              <Option value="g">g</Option>
            </Select>
          </Form.Item>
        </Input.Group>
      </Form.Item>

      <button>SUBMIT</button>
    </Form>
```

Note that you don't need the `key` property.

demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-41wakw?file=demo.tsx

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have lost the format of having the inputs in the same line, even after using nostyle property. Using your code did the trick but I have to style them again I guess.

Comment: Yep, I didn't have the CSS so it looked really janky with the inline styles applied. Adding the style back in shouldn't be too big a deal.

Comment: Turns out I have lost the reason for picking input.group, as tons more divs and rows have come between each of these inputs when using form.item. It is an ordeal actually to style so many divs now so they render in the same line. Sad Ant-design has this issue.

Comment: Seems to work fine: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-41wakw-rknhfs?file=demo.tsx

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is instead of wrapping the entire `<Input.Group>` with a single `<Form.Item>` you need to wrap each `<Input>` with its own `<Form.Item>` and give each one a unique key and name.

[Working Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/other-form-controls-antd-5-0-3-forked-6hfr6j?file=/demo.js:0-1533)

```
   <Input.Group>
    <Form.Item
      name="length"
      key="length"         
    >
      <Input
        style={{ width: '15%' }}
        type="number"
      />
    </Form.Item>
    <Form.Item
      key='breadth'
      name='breadth'
    >
      <Input
        style={{ width: '24%' }}
        addonBefore="x"
        type="number"
      />
    </Form.Item>
      ...
    </Input.Group>
```

Comment: So should I remove the <Form.Item> I have outside the <Input.group> ?

Comment: Thank you for your input, it turns out it was the missing form.item in each element. But Chris's answer was much more articulate.

Comment: Glad I could solve the problem you asked. It was good of Chris to add additional information after the fact.